# JTree cannot see expand tree icons when hiding root

Tags: java, swing, jtree

When I create a JTree and call `setRootVisible(false)`, I cannot see the little tree opening icons, I can still double click on the node to expand it but cannot see them on the first level. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems you need to call [`setShowsRootHandles(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#setShowsRootHandles(boolean)), to see them.